# Spyder3 not launching - How to launch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, spyder

I see other slightly different versions of this question, but not exactly like my situation, so I am asking:

I have installed Python 3.72 on my Windows 8.1 operating system.

Even though I see that Spyder3 and all its dependencies have been installed, I still cannot launch.  Why?  How to launch Spyder3?

```
C:\Python372>pip install pyqt5
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (5.12)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5_sip<4.20,>=4.19.14 in c:\python372\lib\site
-packages (from pyqt5) (4.19.14)

C:\Python372>pip install spyder
Requirement already satisfied: spyder in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (3.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from
spyder) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from spy
der) (18.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: qtpy>=1.5.0 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (fr
om spyder) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (fr
om spyder) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.9.0 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (fr
om spyder) (0.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: spyder-kernels<1.0,>=0.4.2 in c:\python372\lib\si
te-packages (from spyder) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5<=5.12; python_version >= "3" in c:\python37
2\lib\site-packages (from spyder) (5.12)
Requirement already satisfied: pylint in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from sp
yder) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet>=2.0.0 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages
(from spyder) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments>=2.0 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (
from spyder) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (fr
om spyder) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: qtawesome>=0.4.1 in c:\python372\lib\site-package
s (from spyder) (0.5.7)
Requirement already satisfied: qtconsole>=4.2.0 in c:\python372\lib\site-package
s (from spyder) (4.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (fr
om spyder) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from
 spyder) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: keyring; sys_platform != "linux2" in c:\python372
\lib\site-packages (from spyder) (18.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sphinx in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from sp
yder) (1.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpydoc in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from
spyder) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from sp
yder) (5.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rope>=0.10.5 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (f
rom spyder) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parso>=0.3.0 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (f
rom jedi>=0.9.0->spyder) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.2.3 in c:\python372\lib\site-pa
ckages (from spyder-kernels<1.0,>=0.4.2->spyder) (5.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel>=4.8.2 in c:\python372\lib\site-package
s (from spyder-kernels<1.0,>=0.4.2->spyder) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5_sip<4.20,>=4.19.14 in c:\python372\lib\site
-packages (from pyqt5<=5.12; python_version >= "3"->spyder) (4.19.14)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\python372
\lib\site-packages (from pylint->spyder) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7,>=0.6 in c:\python372\lib\site-package
s (from pylint->spyder) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: isort<5,>=4.2.5 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages
 (from pylint->spyder) (4.3.12)
Requirement already satisfied: astroid<3,>=2.2.0 in c:\python372\lib\site-packag
es (from pylint->spyder) (2.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from qtawe
some>=0.4.1->spyder) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from
 qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\python372\lib\site-package
s (from qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (f
rom qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from
nbconvert->spyder) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (fro
m nbconvert->spyder) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat>=4.4 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (
from nbconvert->spyder) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from nb
convert->spyder) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in c:\python372\lib\site-packa
ges (from nbconvert->spyder) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune>=0.8.1 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages
(from nbconvert->spyder) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\python372\lib\site-pac
kages (from nbconvert->spyder) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from nb
convert->spyder) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes!=0.1.0,!=0.1.1; sys_platform == "w
in32" in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from keyring; sys_platform != "linux2"-
>spyder) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: snowballstemmer>=1.1 in c:\python372\lib\site-pac
kages (from sphinx->spyder) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.11 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages
(from sphinx->spyder) (0.14)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.0.0 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages
 (from sphinx->spyder) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from
 sphinx->spyder) (19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (fro
m sphinx->spyder) (40.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: alabaster<0.8,>=0.7 in c:\python372\lib\site-pack
ages (from sphinx->spyder) (0.7.12)
Requirement already satisfied: sphinxcontrib-websupport in c:\python372\lib\site
-packages (from sphinx->spyder) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: imagesize in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from
 sphinx->spyder) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: babel!=2.0,>=1.3 in c:\python372\lib\site-package
s (from sphinx->spyder) (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\python372\lib\site-pac
kages (from jupyter-client>=5.2.3->spyder-kernels<1.0,>=0.4.2->spyder) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.1 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (f
rom jupyter-client>=5.2.3->spyder-kernels<1.0,>=0.4.2->spyder) (6.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=5.0.0 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages
(from ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels<1.0,>=0.4.2->spyder) (7.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from ast
roid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint->spyder) (1.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lazy-object-proxy in c:\python372\lib\site-packag
es (from astroid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint->spyder) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typed-ast>=1.3.0; implementation_name == "cpython
" in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from astroid<3,>=2.2.0->pylint->spyder) (1.
3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from
 traitlets->qtconsole>=4.2.0->spyder) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in c:\python372\lib\site-
packages (from nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->spyder) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (f
rom bleach->nbconvert->spyder) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\python372\lib\site-package
s (from jinja2->nbconvert->spyder) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages
(from requests>=2.0.0->sphinx->spyder) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in c:\python372\lib\site-pa
ckages (from requests>=2.0.0->sphinx->spyder) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python372\lib\site-packa
ges (from requests>=2.0.0->sphinx->spyder) (2018.11.29)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\python372\lib\site-package
s (from packaging->sphinx->spyder) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=0a in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from
babel!=2.0,>=1.3->sphinx->spyder) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\python372\lib\
site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels<1.0,>=0.4.2
->spyder) (2.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from
ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels<1.0,>=0.4.2->spyder) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\python372\lib\site-packa
ges (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->spyder) (0.14.11)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (
from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.4->nbconvert->spyder) (19.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\python372\lib\site-packages (from p
rompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel>=4.8.2->spyder-kernels<1.
0,>=0.4.2->spyder) (0.1.7)

C:\Python372>spyder3

C:\Python372>
```

### EDIT NOW AFTER SOMEONE MARKED THIS AS DUPLICATE:

Not exactly a duplicate since my system is Windows 8.1 and the other question mentios Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. However, the solution offered below the question worked to solve the issue for me partially, i.e. pip install pyqtwebengine. Yet there is problem: Spyder3 starts, but with error which I will post in an "answer" here because of lack of space to post all the code in comments.

I see below that the error message refers to the older Python 3.60 that I removed.  This begs a follow-up question of how I now configure Spyder3 to refer only to the Python 3.72.  I don't want to post a new question because here is already posted the context of how this error message arose.

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python372\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\python372\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "c:\python372\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "c:\python372\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 289, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "D:\DEVELOPMENT_PYTHON360\venv_ml\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in 
from .connect import *
File "D:\DEVELOPMENT_PYTHON360\venv_ml\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in 
import jupyter_client
File "D:\DEVELOPMENT_PYTHON360\venv_ml\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .connect import *
File "D:\DEVELOPMENT_PYTHON360\venv_ml\Lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 22, in 
import zmq
File "D:\DEVELOPMENT_PYTHON360\venv_ml\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 34, in 
from zmq import backend
File "D:\DEVELOPMENT_PYTHON360\venv_ml\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "D:\DEVELOPMENT_PYTHON360\venv_ml\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "D:\DEVELOPMENT_PYTHON360\venv_ml\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "D:\DEVELOPMENT_PYTHON360\venv_ml\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 26, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "D:\DEVELOPMENT_PYTHON360\venv_ml\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython' (D:\DEVELOPMENT_PYTHON360\venv_ml\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

Comment: You might find some useful information [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Troubleshooting-Guide-and-FAQ).

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate since my system is Windows 8.1 and the other question mentios Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.  However, the solution offered below the question worked to solve the issue for me partially, i.e. pip install pyqtwebengine.  Yet there is problem:  Spyder3 starts, but with error which I will post in an "answer" here because of lack of space to post all the code in comments.

Comment: Looks like I can't post here since this was flagged as a duplicate.  You guys really should not be so quick to flag things since this is clearly a separate problem with separate issues now.

Comment: I tried to update the environment variable to remove the reference to Python360, but that didn't work:
C:\Python372\Scripts\;C:\Python372\;C:\Python360\Scripts\;C:\Python360\;%USERPROFILE%\go\bin;C:\Users\yoni\AppData\Roaming\npm

Nonetheless, I went into Spyder and went to TOOLS-->PYTHONPATH MANAGER, and deleted the Spyder internal path to Python360, and reset it to find the current path of Python372.  I restarted Spyder3 and it launches without the previous error message.  PROBLEM SOLVED.  Thanks for previous help, specifically:  pip install pyqtwebengine which got Spyder3 launched.